# Grumby HTML Framework Navigation Sublevels

Tags: html, css, frameworks, navigation

Does anyone use the http://gumbyframework.com? At the moment the navigation menus supplied with the framework only support one sub level. Could anyone help me as I would like to add another level of nav items coming from the right hand side of the second level sub nav. Thanks for your help

Here's my markup:

```
            <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="toggle" data-for=".navbar > ul"><img src="img/icon_nav_toggle.gif" /></a>                                        <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Solutions</a>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Permanent Access</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Temporary Access</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Industrial Rope Access</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Koltek</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FallProtec</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Consult</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

and css:

```
    .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid #1d692d;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #5dbb73; /* Change this to suit the color theme of your site */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar .logo {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar .logo a {
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #114a1e;
}

.navbar > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #114a1e,
                             0 1px 0 #114a1e;
}

.navbar > ul > li .field {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar > ul > li .field .search input {
    line-height: 14px;
}

.navbar > ul > li:hover > a {   
    position: relative;
    background: #05390a;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar > ul > li > li > a {
    padding: 0 33px;
}

.navbar > ul > li:last-child, .navbar > ul > li:last-child a:hover {
    border-right: none;
}


/**** Navbar positioning for Microsoft's browser who deserves not to be mentioned ****/
.ie7 .navbar > ul { width: auto; }

.ie7 .navbar, .ie7 .navbar > ul > li > a { display: block; }

.ie7 .navbar .logo, .ie7 .navbar ul, .ie7 .navbar ul li { float: left; display: inline-block; }

.ie7 .navbar .logo a { display: block; overflow: hidden; }

.ie7 .navbar > ul > li .field { display: block; padding: 12px 18px 0; width: 80%; }

/******** CSS3 Dropdown Menu Styles **********/

.navbar li .dropdown {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 380px;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar li:hover .dropdown {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #1d692d;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);


    -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
    -o-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
    -ms-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
    transition: ease-in-out .2s;
}

.navbar li .dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar li .dropdown ul > li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    font: 16px "Helvetica Neue", arial, sans-serif;
    border-radius: none;
}

.navbar li .dropdown ul > li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.navbar ul .dropdown ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar li .dropdown li a:hover {
    background: #ebfeee;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .navbar, .pretty.navbar {
      position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar .logo {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
  }

  .navbar a.toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 10px; /* Move me around */
    top: 10px; /* Move me around */
    background: #3c8f4f;
    width: 42px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition-duration: .1s;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition-duration: .1s;  /* IE10 */
    -o-transition-duration: .1s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition-duration: .1s;
  }

  .pretty.navbar a.toggle {
    border: 1px solid #1d692d;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%, #2d9047 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5dbb73), color-stop(100%,#2d9047)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5dbb73', endColorstr='#2d9047',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #94dda6,
        0 1px 1px #94dda6;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #94dda6,
      0 1px 1px #94dda6;
  }

  .navbar a.toggle:hover, .navbar a.toggle.active {
    background: #5dbb73;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .1s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition-duration: .1s;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition-duration: .1s;  /* IE10 */
    -o-transition-duration: .1s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition-duration: .1s;
  }

  .navbar a.toggle.active {
    background: #114a1e;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 93.75%;
    height: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    top: 54px;
    right: 3.125%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;

    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition-duration: .2s;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition-duration: .2s;  /* IE10 */
    -o-transition-duration: .2s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition-duration: .2s;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }

  .navbar ul.active {
    width: 93.75%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition-duration: .5s;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition-duration: .5s;  /* IE10 */
    -o-transition-duration: .5s;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }

  .navbar ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .pretty.navbar ul li {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .navbar ul li > a {
        font-size: 22px !important;
        border: 1px solid #1d692d;
        background: #5dbb73; /* Old browsers */
  }

  .navbar > ul > li .field {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 90%;
  }

  .navbar > ul > li .search {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ccc;
  }

  .navbar li a:hover, .navbar > ul > li:first-child, .navbar > ul > li:first-child a:hover, .navbar > ul > li:last-child, .navbar > ul > li:last-child a:hover {    
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .navbar > ul > li:last-child, .navbar > ul > li:last-child a:hover {
    border-right: none;
  }

  .navbar li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0 !important;
  }

  .navbar li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px !important;
  }

  .navbar li:hover .dropdown {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar ul li > a {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #d04526;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: none;
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  .navbar ul li:hover > a {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

  .pretty.navbar {
    border: 1px solid #1d692d;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%, #2d9047 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5dbb73), color-stop(100%,#2d9047)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #5dbb73 0%,#2d9047 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5dbb73', endColorstr='#2d9047',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #94dda6,
        0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.61) !important; /* Remove this line if you dont want a dropshadow on your buttons*/
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #94dda6,
                0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.61) !important; /* Remove this line if you dont want a dropshadow on your buttons*/
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .pretty.navbar ul li .btn {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

}
```

Thanks for any answers!! Cheers, Paul

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if your're using Gumby 1 or 2. But in the 2 this seems to work.

```
  <div class="navbar" id="nav1">
    <div class="row">
      <a class="toggle" gumby-trigger="#nav1 > .row > ul" href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
      <h1 class="four columns logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/gumby_mainlogo.png" gumby-retina />
        </a>
      </h1>
      <ul class="eight columns">
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Documentation</a>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">I HAVE STUFF NESTED UNDER ME</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">nested</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </div>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Customize</a></li>
        <li class="field"><input class="search input" type="search" placeholder="Search" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```